# PHP can't POST the selected value from a dropdown

Tags: php, json, forms, post

```
          <form action="addbusstop.php" method="POST" id="produceJSON" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <?php
        echo "<div class = 'dropdown_container'><select class = 'dropdown select xs-mt1' name = 'line' id = 'line'>";
        foreach($ptv_json_bus as $item)
        {
          $stopid = $item['stop_id'];
          $stopname = $item['location_name'];

          ?>

          <option value = "<?php echo $stopid;?>"> <?php echo $stopname;?></option>

          <?php
        }//end foreach
        ?>
        <input type = "hidden" value ="<?php echo $stopid; ?>" name="stop_id" id="stop_id">
        <input type = "hidden" value ="<?php echo $stopname; ?>" name="stop_name" id="stop_name">
      </select>

      <button type="submit" class="button button-latrobe-orange xs-ml2" onclick="changeState3()" id="submitstop2" name="submitstop2">OK</button>
    </div>


  </form>
```

Hey guys. Above is the code I'm working with.

What I am trying to achieve is to POST the selected value's stop ID and stop NAME (from a dropdown) to another file which then adds the data into mySQL.

What my problem is right now is that the current code I have is actually only POSTing the last set value of $stopid and $stopname which is not what I need.

I've been stuck on this for quite a while and I would love it it somebody here could point me in the right direction!!

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move your `<input>` elements outside of the `<select>` element.
You can only put `<option>` elements inside of your `<select>` element.

I've improved your version a bit.

```
<form action="addbusstop.php" method="POST" id="produceJSON" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class = 'dropdown_container'>
        <select class="dropdown select xs-mt1" name="line" id="line">
            <?php
            foreach ($ptv_json_bus as $item) {
                $stopid = $item['stop_id'];
                $stopname = $item['location_name'];
                echo "<option value='$stopid'>$stopname</option>";
            }
            ?>
        </select>
        <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $stopid; ?>" name="stop_id" id="stop_id">
        <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $stopname; ?>" name="stop_name" id="stop_name">

        <button type="submit" class="button button-latrobe-orange xs-ml2" onclick="changeState3()" id="submitstop2" name="submitstop2">OK</button>
    </div>
</form>
```